# full width select menu combined with buttons in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, select

I am trying to get a footer toolbar, consisting of two buttons (prev/next) and a selectmenu.
How can I make the selectmenu use the full width?

See [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wivaku/Ln2fkmfs/) for details.

Using a controlgroup makes it look the way I want/need, except that it does not fill the full width.
I also experimented with fieldset, navbar, grids, but so far not the wanted result.

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="footerControlgroup" >
  <button id="prev" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini">Prev</button>
  <button id="next" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-notext ui-mini">Next</button>
  <select id="select" data-mini="true">
    <option>pick me...</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Part of jQuery Mobile's styling/markup on form elements in the footer navigation  modifies the typical full width dropdown to an inline dropdown that floats to the left or right. Any customization will need to be made with some CSS and simple html structure

Comment: Same result when you put the controlgroup in the main content section. So, not sure it is footer specific. What CSS / simple HTML do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Here is the complete solution: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wivaku/sL80sn3d/).

The key part of the solution:

```
var select = $("#mySelect");
var cWidth = 0;
select.closest(".ui-controlgroup-controls").children().not(".ui-select")
    .each(function() { 
        cWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
        $(this).outerHeight( select.closest(".ui-select").height() +0.5 );
    });
select.closest(".ui-select").find(".ui-btn")
  .outerWidth( select.closest("[data-role='controlgroup']").width() - cWidth -1);
```

The tricky parts that it deals with:

- jQuery Mobile inserts various elements to enhance the select
- jQuery Mobile has two types of select menu's: native, or custom (option list enhanced by JQM)
- jQuery Mobile select can be full size or data-mini="true"
- traversing is slightly different when using inside a footer (although the DOM structure is the same)
- I made it generic so the number of elements (e.g. buttons) before or after the select is variable
- this is a static function, so I bind it to a .resize to adjust the width when resizing the browser

In case you are interested: the structure of the jQuery Mobile select menu's:

**native select**

```
div data-role=controlgroup
    div .ui-controlgroup-controls
        button #prev .ui-btn 
        button #next .ui-btn
        div .ui-select
            div #<selectId>-button .ui-btn          <== adjust width
                span <text of first item>
                select #<selectId>                  <-- starting point
```

**custom select**

```
div data-role=controlgroup
    div .ui-controlgroup-controls
        button #prev .ui-btn 
        button #next .ui-btn
        div .ui-select
            a #<selectId>-button .ui-btn            <== adjust width
                span <text of first item>
            select #<selectId>                      <-- starting point
            div #<selectId>-listbox-placeholder
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the credit, but this is more complicated than I realized.  Great job!

Answer (score 1):

This may get you going:

```
var next= document.getElementById('next');
var select= document.getElementById('select');
select.style.width= 
  (select.parentNode.offsetWidth -
   next.getBoundingClientRect().right
  )+'px';
```